# SQL query to extract the part of matching SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's consider a `CLASS` and `BILL` table.

`CLASS` table:

| Class | Description |
| --- | --- |
| F | Factory |
| H | Headoffice |
| C001 | Electrical |
| C002 | Mechanical |
| C003 | Civil |

`BILL` table:

| BILL_NO | DOCCLASS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FC001 |
| 2 | FC002 |
| 3 | FC003 |

Description: `Class` is a primary key. Let's say we created invoices by tagging  different class from the `CLASS` table.

For example invoice 1 is created by tagging `FCOO1` (ie. Factory and  Electrical)

Problem: how to write a SQL query to get only `COO1` part from `FC001` of Invoice 1?

This SQL code is not working:

```
Select
    BILLDET.BILL_NO,
    BILLDET.CLASS,
    BILLDET.GLCODE,
    CLASS.DESCRIPT
From
    BILLDET 
Full Join 
    CLASS On BILLDET.CLASS = CLASS.CLASS
```

Output:

| Bill NO | DESCRIPT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FactoryElectrical |

Thank you

Comment: This is a badly designed table: store *one single* piece of information per column

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, what a way to store data

```
WITH classx AS(
  SELECT
    c.class+n.class as class,
    c.descript+n.descript as descript 
  FROM
    class c 
    JOIN class n 
    ON 
      c.class LIKE 'c%' AND 
      n.class NOT LIKE 'c%'
)

SELECT * FROM bill JOIN classx ON bill.docclass = classx.class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select bill_no, Description
from
(
select c2.class + c1.class as keys, c2.description+c1.description as Description
from class c1, class c2
where c1.class LIKE 'c%' AND 
      c2.class NOT LIKE 'c%'
)as tab, bill
where keys = DOCCLASS;
```